# TFS - annotate - View changes before last change

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I usually use annotate to view who changed the code in TFS. But it's only showing latest changeset.

For example line 320 was changed by:

- Changeset 5276 at 27/10/2010
- Changeset 14219 at 12/11/2014
- Changeset 110697 at 11/02/2015

The annotation only shows:

```
110697 John Smith  11/02/2015      320 nErrorNo = cmd.GetDBErrorNo();
```

There is no way showing other two changesets.

I tried using "History..." at the source file, and choose two different changesets to compare, but it's still not convenience to find out other changesets of that line.

Is there an easy way to find out all changesets that contributed to one line?

Comment: Are you making a statement, or do you have a question?

Comment: If the annotate only show one changeset?  How did you get the info line 320 was changed by  5276/14219?

Comment: @Patrick By selecting from history versions and check line 320 I can find it was changed by other changesets, but it's tedious as you have to open every history versions one by one.

Comment: Did this phenomenon only happened on the one file or  all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an interesting information for annotate. With the same file, **the Changeset IDs of annotate and history are not correspond one by one.**
[image]

In other words, this function of annotate only shows the Changeset which including the changes made to the content of the file. So if the old Changeset are doing something like merge, rename file, moving location. Then this Changeset will not shown in the annotation. Please check the changes of this Changeset 5276/14219. Maybe it's a normal phenomenon. More info for [annotate from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979(v=vs.140).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I'd only like to know changes to some specific lines. I have a very large file which lots of changesets had contributed to it, but only very few of them changed say line 320. I'd like to find out what they are.